# Em Python existe operação ternária?

Tags: python, operadores, condição

Costumo ver várias linguagens de programações onde uma operação ternária é quase sempre idêntica.

```
(x % 2 == 0) ? "par" : "impar"
```

Porém, quando fui tentar fazer isso no Python, deu erro:

```
(x % 2 == 0) ? "par" : "impar"
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

se assim não funciona, então como seria uma operação ternária em Python?

Comment: Lembrando que esse operador não se chama _ternário_ mas sim **_condicional_**. Acontece que ele costuma ser o único operador ternário (ou seja, que recebe três operandos) das linguagens nas quais ele aparece, por isso a forte associação.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Existe sim, no Python é conhecido como [Expressão Condicional](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

```
<expressao1> if <condicao> else <expressao2>
```

Primeiro, a condição é avaliada (ao invés de `expressao1`), se a condição for verdadeira, `expressao1` é avaliada e seu valor é retornado; caso contrário, `expressao2` é avaliada e seu valor retornado.

Com base no teu exemplo, o código fica assim:

```
x = 10
print ("par" if x % 2 == 0 else "impar")
```

---

Uma alternativa com [operadores booleanos `and` e `or`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

```
<condicao> and <expressao1> or <expressao2>
```

No entanto, não funciona do mesmo modo que uma Expressão Condicional, se a condição for verdadeira, `expressao1` é avaliada e seu valor retornado; se `expressao1` for falso, `expressao2` é avaliada e seu valor retornado.

Com base no teu exemplo:

```
x = 10
print (x % 2 == 0 and "par" or "impar")
```

---

De acordo com o [PEP *308*, Conditional Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/), a razão por não ter sido implementado a sintaxe `<condicao> ? <expressao1> : <expressao2>` usado em muitas [linguagens derivadas do C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C-family_programming_languages) é:

> (Em tradução livre)
>
> [**Eric Raymond**](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3882) até implementou isto.
>
> O [**BDFL**](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BDFL) rejeitou isto por várias razões: o dois-pontos já tem muitos usos em Python (embora, na verdade, não seria ambíguo, porque o ponto de
> interrogação exige o dois-pontos correspondente); para as pessoas que não
> usam linguagens derivadas do C, é difícil de entender.

<sub>Obs: **BDFL** (Benevolent Dictator For Life): Guido van Rossum, criador do Python.</sub>

Comment: Hum... Que interessante. O "se deu" fica antes do `if` e o "se não" depois do `else`.

Comment: Isso é realmente um ternário ou é um syntax sugar do Python?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Está mais para operador ternário, de uma olhada no *link* da documentação e no PEP para ver a discussão... =)

Comment: Vou te dar uma moral :p. Foi difícil escolher uma. Depois boto recompensa para não chatear ninguém :p

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Valeu, editei a resposta para esclarecer algumas coisas..

Comment: Parece que você é fã de Python, né?

Answer (score 12):

Em Python o `if` pode ser usado tanto como um *statement*, como um operador em contextos diferentes. Como operador dá para fazer assim:

```
print(1 if True else 2)
```

No seu exemplo:

```
x = randint(0,9)
print ("par" if x % 2 == 0 else "impar")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rN3Rwb). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tobikekx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Ternary.py).

Ele pega o primeiro valor se a condição for verdadeira, se a condição for falsa ele pega o que está no `else`. Genericamente falando a expressão condicional (não gosto do termo ternário) fica assim:

```
valorVerdadeito if condicao else valorFalso
```

Answer (score 7):

Sim, na operação ternaria você utiliza o `if` e `else` normalmente.

```
y = "par" if x % 2 == 0 else "impar"
```

Answer (score 7):

A linguagem [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) possui sua própria sintaxe para operação ternária. O que difere da maioria que utilizam a conhecida sintaxe (`condição ? verdadeiro : false`).

A sua expressão com `if` e `else` "normal" ficaria:

```
if x % 2 == 0:
    print "Par"
else:
    print "Ímpar"
```

Passando para operação ternária do Python, ficaria:

```
print "Par" if x % 2 == 0 else "Ímpar"
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/pXCqaF).

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions

Comment: Da doc fica melhor ainda :p. Pena que tá em inglês

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, coloquei a documentação porque é a fonte mais confiável. Em português tem o pythonBrasil. http://wiki.python.org.br/SimulandoOperadorTernario

Answer (score 1):

Um jeito interessante de se fazer também é:

```
('impar', 'par')[x%2==0]
```

Fica até mais simples na minha opinião

Answer (score -4):

A função utiliza um operador ternário para calcular o MDC de dois números

```
def mdc(a,b):
  return b if (a == 0) else mdc(b % a, a)
```