# Django request.GET

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Existe alguma forma mais simples de fazer isso?

```
 if "id_parada" in request.GET:
     id_parada = request.GET["id_parada"]
 else:
     id_parada = ''
```

Comment: Leandro, já verificou esta resposta: [Em Python existe operação ternária?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/161508/110782)  ?

Comment: Luiz já melhorou um pouco  ficaria assim  `id_parada = request.GET["id_parada"] if "id_parada" in request.GET else '' `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira mais simples é:

```py
id_parada = request.GET.get("id_parada", "")
```

Neste caso você está usando o método `.get()` para recuperar o conteúdo da chave `id_parada` em `request.GET` e, caso ela não exista, retornar "" (o padrão é `None`).

Comment: Show, Obrigado resolveu perfeitamente!

Comment: [Este é o link para a documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get), caso alguém se interesse...