# Como obter o índice do primeiro elemento positivo em uma lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Estou procurando uma solução para um problema bem simples. Preciso obter o primeiro elemento de uma lista maior ou igual a zero.

Consegui fazer isso com a seguinte função:

```
def index_of_first_positive_element(values):
    for idx, val in enumerate(values):
        if val >= 0:
            return idx
    return -1

first_positive_idx = index_of_first_positive_element([-10, -5, 3, 15])
print(first_positive_idx) # 2
```

Minha função funciona, porém minha intuição me diz que deve existir uma maneira mais curta, direta e/ou idiomática de fazer isso. Talvez alguma função *built-in*, técnica funcional ou um pythonismo qualquer (e.g., *list comprehension*).

Dentro do possível eu gostaria de uma técnica eficiente. Prefiro técnicas que, como no código acima, parem no primeiro elemento positivo ao invés de técnicas que acumulem todos os elementos positivos em uma lista intermediária.

Alguém tem idéia de como fazer isso?

P.S.: Soluções envolvendo bibliotecas também são bem vindas (só por favor não se esqueça de deixar um link para a(s) biblioteca(s) utilizadas e incluir os *imports* necessários para fazer seu código funcionar).

**Atribuição:**

A pergunta é original, mas a idéia foi adaptada de [*First Python list index greater than x?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2236906/664577)

Comment: Parte da minha iniciativa para trazer mais perguntas para a comunidade.

Comment: Eu não acho que o seu código não seja _pythonico_. :-)

Comment: Hehehe, justo. Digamos então que estou procurando por soluções aternativas igualmente idiomáticas :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pergunta pede que se retorne o **índice** do primeiro elemento positivo, mas [uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/496494/112052) está retornando o próprio elemento. Sendo assim, bastaria uma pequena modificação:

```
def index_of_first_positive_element(values):
    return next((idx for idx, val in enumerate(values) if val >= 0), -1)

print(index_of_first_positive_element([-10, -5, 3, 15])) # 2
print(index_of_first_positive_element([-10, -5, -15])) # -1
```

O [built-in `next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) recebe dois argumentos:

- um iterador: no caso, `(idx for idx, val in enumerate(values) if val >= 0)`, que é uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). Ela é similar à [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), porém a diferença é que ela não cria uma lista. O *generator* é "lazy", no sentido de que só devolve seus elementos à medida em que forem necessários (ou seja, não há a criação - neste caso desnecessária - de uma lista)
- um valor *default*, caso não haja mais elementos no iterador. Como estamos chamando `next` apenas uma vez em um *generator* recém-criado, então será o valor retornado caso ele esteja vazio (no caso, se a lista não tiver nenhum elemento maior ou igual a zero)

Assim, cada chamada de `next` consome o próximo elemento do *generator*, e como eu só chamei uma vez, será retornado o primeiro (ou `-1` caso não haja nenhum elemento que safisfaça a condição `val >= 0`).

Acho que isso é o mais sucinto (e [*pythônico*](/q/192343/112052)?) que podemos chegar.

---

Mas claro que tem outros jeitos (talvez não tão "simples" quanto o método acima).

Uma opção é usar `filter`:

```
def index_of_first_positive_element(values):
    return next(filter(lambda x: x[1] >= 0, enumerate(values)), (-1, ))[0]
```

Mas como precisamos do índice, e cada elemento retornado por `enumerate` é uma tupla (contendo o índice e o respectivo elemento), o valor *default* do `next` também deve ser uma tupla.

Claro que aí poderia ser usado `map` para obter o primeiro elemento da tupla:

```
def index_of_first_positive_element(values):
    return next(map(lambda x: x[0], filter(lambda x: x[1] >= 0, enumerate(values))), -1)
```

Mas na minha opinião, já estamos complicando demais algo que deveria ser simples (e de fato é, basta usar a primeira solução acima).

Também tem opções com o [módulo `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) (que para mim, são igualmente - ou talvez mais - complicados que as opções anteriores com `filter` e `map`, mas fica aqui como curiosidade):

```
from itertools import dropwhile
def index_of_first_positive_element(values):
    return next(dropwhile(lambda x: x[1] < 0, enumerate(values)), (-1, ))[0]
```

---

Só para constar, podemos generalizar este problema para a enésima ocorrência (em vez de somente a primeira), e aí o módulo `itertools` vem a calhar:

```
from itertools import islice

def index_of_nth_element(values, n, predicate, default=None):
    return next(
        islice((idx for idx, val in enumerate(values) if predicate(val)), n - 1, None),
        default
    )

lista = [-1, -2, 3, -5, -7, 10, -1]
# pega a primeira ocorrência
print(index_of_nth_element(lista, 1, lambda x: x >= 0, -1)) # 2
# pega a segunda ocorrência
print(index_of_nth_element(lista, 2, lambda x: x >= 0, -1)) # 5
# pega a terceira ocorrência (que não existe)
print(index_of_nth_element(lista, 3, lambda x: x >= 0, -1)) # -1
# não tem elementos que satisfazem a condição
print(index_of_nth_element(lista, 2, lambda x: x >= 1000000, -1)) # -1
```

Mas claro que se você quer sempre a primeira ocorrência, usar `itertools` é desnecessário.

Comment: Eu particularmente achei a solução da pergunta a mais pythonica até agora hahaha simples, direta, fácil de entender e fácil de manter - considerando apenas o problema de primeira ocorrência.

Comment: @Woss É, eu tb acho o código da pergunta mais simples, por isso mesmo escrevi "*(e pythônico **?**)*", pois acho que ser "mais pythônico" é meio subjetivo em alguns casos... Mas enfim, a pergunta pedia por alternativas, se vai ser mais pythonico ou não, vai de cada um :-)

Comment: Acho que o problema aqui estava mais na minha pergunta do que nas respostas. Tirei a passagem sobre solução pythonica e reforcei que estou buscando algo curto direto e/ou idiomático, assim evitamos o debate sobre o que é ou não é pythonico. De qualquer forma a combinação de `next` + iteradores funciona muito bem. E na ausência de algo como o [`indexWhere` em Scala](https://ideone.com/ULZuds) eu diria que [a resposta do Lucas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/496494/100) e a adaptação para retornar o índice do hkotsubo representam um bom meio termo entre código curto e expressivo.

Answer (score 9):

Uma função built-in utilizável no seu exemplo seria a `next`. Dado uma regra, ele então retorna o próximo item do seu iterador.
Exemplo de uso:

```
seq = [-10, -5, 3, 15]
print(next((x for x in seq if x >= 0) , -1 ))
```

**Atualização:**

Essa resposta não reproduz corretamente o pedido pela pergunta, recuperando apenas o valor e não o `index`. Para resposta correta olhar a [resposta do hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/496488/como-obter-o-%C3%ADndice-do-primeiro-elemento-positivo-em-uma-lista/496518#496518).

Comment: Você está correto, atualizei passando o valor default

Comment: `print(next((i for i,x in enumerate(seq) if x >= 0) , -1 ))`

Comment: Por que você julgaria essa solução pythonica?

Comment: @Woss , na verdade não considero, não conhecia a terminologia e estou olhando agora, acredito que a resposta mais completa seja a do hkotsubo

Comment: @LucasMiranda, não foi esse o objetivo da pergunta do Woss. É uma retórica o lembrando que a pergunta que suscitou sua resposta [antes da edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/496488/3) começava assim *Estou procurando uma solução pythonica....* então a pergunta *Por que você julgaria essa solução pythonica?* é uma sugestão para que explane em sua resposta o por que ou o que torna seu código idiomático. Da minha parte, analise o meu comentário anterior e veja se ele pode contribuir com a sua resposta. obtenha mais informações [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/192347/137387).

Comment: Eu entendi! Na verdade eu respondi essa pergunta de forma despretensiosa, não manjo muito de python, como a minha resposta está errada eu evitei ficar dando muito atenção pra ela pra não preterir a resposta correta

Answer (score 3):

Se no lugar da lista estivermos trabalhando com um arranjo 1D do `numpy`, podemos fazer da seguinte forma:

```
import numpy as np

def index_of_first_positive_element(array: np.ndarray):
    bool_array = array >= 0
    return bool_array.argmax() if bool_array.sum() else -1

a = np.array([-10, -5, 3, 15])
first_positive_idx = index_of_first_positive_element(a)
print(first_positive_idx) # 2
```

#### Explicação:

Aqui utilizei o fato de que os valores booleanos `True` e `False` correspondem aos números `1` e `0`, respectivamente. Podemos confirmar isso mesmo com listas comuns:

```
>>> sum([True, True])
2
```

na primeira linha da função, a variável `bool_array` é definida como sendo `array >= 0`. Como `array` é um arranjo do `numpy`, essa sintaxe significa *criar um arranjo de valores booleanos representando se cada elemento do arranjo inicial é maior ou igual a zero*. Ou seja, se

`array = np.array([-1, 0, 5])`,

então

`bool_array = array >= 0`

é um arranjo com os valores `[False, True, True]`.

Na segunda linha, utilizo o método [`np.ndarray.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argmax.html#numpy.ndarray.argmax), que retorna *o índice do elemento de maior valor de um arranjo* (e se houver empate entre 2 elementos, retorna a primeira ocorrência). Como o arranjo em questão é somente composto de `True` e `False`, isso equivale a retornar o índice do primeiro valor `True` (lembrando que `True` vale `1`, `False` vale `0`), que é justamente o primeiro elemento positivo.

Ainda temos que lidar com o caso quando nenhum valor é maior que zero; neste caso, `bool_array` apenas tem elementos `False`, e `np.ndarray.argmax` retornará (erroneamente) o índice 0. Para isso, utilizei a [expressão condicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161505/em-python-existe-opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-tern%C3%A1ria) testando a condição `if bool_array.sum()`. Essa condição apenas será falsa quando a soma do arranjo booleano for zero, ou, em outras palavras, quando não houver valores positivos no arranjo inicial. Neste caso, retornamos o valor sentinela `-1`.