# Desejo saber como mostrar, para o usuário, Sim ou Não no lugar de True ou False, respectivamente

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, booleano

Abaixo está um exemplo do que estou tentando fazer:

```
lm = input ('Digite uma letra ')
print ('essa é uma letra minúscula? {}' .format(lm.islower()))
```

Já tentei colocar `True = Sim` e `False = Não`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que processar isso condicionalmente e apresentar o que deseja. O resultado de um booleano não foi feito para ser apresentado a não ser em circunstâncias muitos específicas.

```
lm = input ('Digite uma letra ')
print('essa é uma letra minúscula? {}'.format('Sim' if lm.islower() else 'Não'))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QZs4aE). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/adgsruny-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/ChooseString.py).

Pode [ver mais sobre a expressão com operador condicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/161505/101) (que alguns chama de ternário).

Se for o que condicionou ele pega o primeiro resultado antes do `if`, caso contrário pega o resultado após o `else`, e o resultado de toda essa expressão é que será impressa.

Você [pode usar f-strings](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264702/101) também, apenas para modernizar.